# What is the pin number for PWM outputs on RPI3 model B?

Tags: pwm

What is the pin number for PWM on RPI 3 model B?

On the RPI2 i used to 18 pin, I used to set it up like

> "gpio -g mode 18 pwm"

However, is it same on the RPI 3?

Where can I found the doc,  usually gpio pin 18 used to PWM on RPI?

I've got the pin info with this commands.
However, I have no idea on RPI3 .

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpio readall

I want to know how to I set the PWM pins from this chart.

Answer (score 3):

There are two hardware PWM channels. Channel 0 is available on GPIO 12 and 18.  Channel 1 is available on GPIO 13 and 19.

You can use the [pigs hp](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#HP) command to set hardware PWM (requires the pigpio daemon to be running, `sudo pigpiod`).

You can also use DMA timed PWM on all GPIO.  You can use the [pigs p](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#P/PWM) command to set DMA PWM.